How do I integrate Cypress with Jenkins and Testrail?
I'm trying to run my cypress project remotely from a github repo and post the results on testrail, all of this with jenkins.
Now everything is fine till I actually run the tests and generate the report and then the job crashes with:
"Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE"
This is my "Execute Windows Batch Command":
REM Install Cypress
npm install cypress

REM Delete previous report files if they exist
if exist reports\*.xml (
    del /Q reports\*.xml
)
echo "Deleted old reports"

REM Create the reports folder if it doesn't exist
if not exist reports (
    mkdir reports
)
echo "Reports folder is ready"
@echo off

REM Run Cypress tests
npx cypress run --browser chrome --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=reports/[hash].xml,useFullSuiteTitle=true,testsuiteTitle=true" --env codePage=UTF-8

REM Wait for reports to generate
echo Waiting for reports to generate...
timeout /t 5}

REM Post the generated reports to TestRail
echo Posting reports to TestRail...
trcli -y -h "https://generic.testrail.io" -u "generic@email.com" -p "generic" --project "cypress-testrail" parse_junit -f ".\reports\*.xml" --title "Automated Jenkins Test Run"

echo "Reports successfully posted to TestRail"

I have no clue what I am doing. This worked locally when I tried to post my results to testrail, but now it stops after "npx cypress run..." I know for a fact that it won't be able to run the trcli command either, so...
Is there another way to post my cypress test results on testrail from Jenkins? or how do I fix my build steps so that they work?
